Getting shared mailbox permissions with parallel processing
I'm trying to improve performance in a script that gets all shared mailboxes that a user has delegate access to in Exchange Online. The script finds mailboxes where the user has "Read and Manage" and "Send As" access, but we can just focus on the "Read and Manage" part for this discussion. The "Send As" part is very similar, but uses the Get-EXORecipientPermission cmdlet. I'd like a solution for PowerShell 5.1 (Windows), but don't mind examples in PowerShell 7 (core). I'd also prefer a solution that outputs to the host as it goes, but this wouldn't matter if I could make it blazing fast.
Here's a simplified version of what I have using a single thread. We must enumerate each shared mailbox and call into Exchange Online to check the delegates, which takes a long time.
function Show-ReadManageMailboxes($mailboxesToSearch, $userEmail)
{
    Write-Host "Getting mailboxes where user has `"Read and Manage`" access. Please wait..." -ForegroundColor "DarkCyan"
    $mailboxesToSearch |
    ForEach-Object {
        $permission = Get-EXOMailboxPermission -Identity $_ -User $userEmail -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
        if (-not($permission)) { return } # This return statement continues to next object in pipeline. It doesn't return from the function.
        $totalMailboxesWithReadAndManage++
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Display Name"  = $_.DisplayName
            "UPN"           = $_.UserPrincipalName
            "Access Rights" = $permission.AccessRights
        }
    } | Format-Table

    Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor "Green"
}

$userEmail = "Example.User@domain.com"
$allMailboxes = Get-EXOMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox, GroupMailbox, TeamMailbox
Show-ReadManageMailboxes -mailboxesToSearch $allMailboxes -userEmail $userEmail

If I understand right, thread jobs would be the best thing to try here. Here's what I've tried:
function Show-ReadManageMailboxes($mailboxesToSearch, $userEmail)
{
    Write-Host "Getting mailboxes where user has `"Read and Manage`" access. Please wait..." -ForegroundColor "DarkCyan"
    $mailboxesToSearch |
    ForEach-Object {
        Start-ThreadJob -ThrottleLimit $mailboxesToSearch.Count {
            Get-EXOMailboxPermission -Identity $using:_ -User $using:userEmail -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
        }
    } | Receive-Job -Wait | Format-Table  
    
    Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor "Green"
}

This outputs the mailboxes quicker, but still takes forever to complete. Almost like it gets hung up trying to stop/remove all the jobs.
I've also tried this in PowerShell 7, which behaves similarly:
function Show-ReadManageMailboxes($mailboxesToSearch, $userEmail)
{
    Write-Host "Getting mailboxes where user has `"Read and Manage`" access. Please wait..." -ForegroundColor "DarkCyan"
    $mailboxesToSearch |
    ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit $mailboxesToSearch.Count -AsJob -Parallel { 
        Get-EXOMailboxPermission -Identity $_ -User $using:userEmail -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
    } | Receive-Job -Wait | Format-Table  

    Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor "Green"
}

Can this be done better?

A few ideas, try using graph calls as it may be able to handle batches more efficiently that the cmdlets potentially. Rather than the EXO prefix command, connect to exchange online then just use Get-MailboxPermissions since the non-EXO should be REST backed. Another solution if feasible in your environment, have a job that dumps all shared mailbox permissions with applicable attributes to a 5 AM csv file, then have your scripts use the daily csv file. Not sure if a daily would suffice but in your case, but just an idea to consider.

One last idea, tie your shared mailbox accounts to an AD group like sm_read-<mailbox>, sm_sendas-<mailbox>, etc. as a standard at setup time, & use these groups to automate the additions/removals without having to check each, & just knowing per group membership which is setup & used as a standard, & then you can just query those ones to add/remove & a command to confirm effective change against it otherwise. Not sure what you are doing, but I have slews of staff termination & new hire scripts with various methods incorporated. Maybe 50-100 shared mailboxes total in that domain though.

@BitcoinMurderousManiac Thank you. There is no support for Exchange Online in Microsoft graph currently.  Using the non-exo cmdlets doesn't improve performance (in fact the EXO versions are supposed to be more performant). Caching the data is not really feasible for us. Thank you though.

@BitcoinMurderousManiac Re-architecting the way we assign mailbox permissions is not really a feasible solution either, well at least right now, but thank you for the ideas. I'm really just hoping to see if I can improve performance of our PowerShell scripts that fetch this data, and make sure that I'm doing parallel processing correctly, as I'm not very experienced with parallel/asynchronous stuff.
